# Create SMPTE timecode track for a QuickTime movie with AVFoundation

Tags: objective-c, osx-lion, avfoundation, quicktime, avassetwriter

I am trying to write a program that adds an SMPTE timecode track to a QuickTime movie, so that I can use this movie in professional editing applications like Final Cut or Avid.

There is a nice example from Apple that explains how to do this with the QTKit-Framework: [Code Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/QTKitTimeCode/Listings/QTTimeCode_c.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004426-QTTimeCode_c-DontLinkElementID_5)

But since QTKit is 32-bit and AVFoundation will be its 64-bit Replacement, I need to know if this is possible with AVFoundation?

Answer (score 0):

I just pulled an iPhone video into FCP, and it has valid NTSC timecode. It just starts at 01:00:00:00 for each clip. If you want a time-of-day type timecode, then I would suggest generating a timestamped THM file that can be used by programs like qtChange to embed the timecode to QT files. This is how to manage timecode in Canon 5D  workflows.

Comment: I don't actually think that's true.  FCP is presenting the file with that timecode, but that's not embedded inside the file.  Any file you bring into FCP without TC will start at HR 1.